# Problems sending TCP socket from localhost to localhost with rammbock library of Robotframework

Tags: python, robotframework

I'm using Robotframework and I need to send a JSON message to a program that listens on port 80. Since I'm sending this JSON from my computer to a program that is also installed on my computer I assume (with my little Networks knowledge) that the sending and the receiving IP would be 127.0.0.1.

In this particular piece of code I send a integer to a template that creates a JSON structure with this argument and sends it to localhost port 80, the socket needs to be TCP.

This is my code:

```
*** Test Cases ***
      Set Simulator CDC
      [Tags]    cdc
      [Template]    Set Simulator CDC Template
      #${cdc}
      3120

*** Keywords ***
      Set Simulator CDC Template
      [Arguments]    ${cdc}    ${status}=0    ${connection}=${SIMULATOR_CONNECTION}
      ${cdc}=    Convert to Integer    ${cdc}
      ${json_cdc}=    Create Dictionary    command=cdc    cdc=${cdc}
      ${json_cdc}=    json.Dumps    ${json_cdc}
      Log    ${json_cdc}
      New Protocol    simpleRequest
      Chars    *    ${json_cdc}
      End Protocol
      Start TCP server    127.0.0.1    12454    protocol=simpleRequest
      Start TCP client    protocol=simpleRequest
      Connect    127.0.0.1    80
      New Message    ${json_cdc}    simpleRequest
      u32    status
      Client Sends message
      ${msg}=    Server Receives Message
      Should be equal    ${msg.status.hex}    ${status}
```

I'm not sure if you can create the protocol with variable type 'Chars' being a JSON but when converting the JSON to string the result is the same. Log file only gives error on keyword 'Server Receives Message' but I installed Wireshark and I don't see any packet goint to 127.0.0.1 and the program that should receive the JSON won't receive a thing.

Thanks in advance;

Manuel González García

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are starting your server on port 12454 instead of 80, you should change this line :

```
Start TCP server    127.0.0.1    12454    protocol=simpleRequest
```

to

```
Start TCP server    127.0.0.1    80    protocol=simpleRequest
```

It also seems that your code is missing indentation, which seems required by rammbock

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. About the identation i pasted the code without identation, now I edited the message. About the port I already tried with port 80 and it doesn't work. I assumed though that if I'm sending a message on localhost it wouldn't be logical to send that message from the same port that receives it.